# how to disable one of the radio button after the registration form is submit in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to disable one of the radio button from 4 radio buttons after the form is submitted
in php

Comment: There is no question. Probably you forgot the question mark. But: Which one do you want to disable, a random one?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. If you want an answer to your question, try providing more, specific information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//when you submit the form
$(".submitbutton").click(function() {  

  $.ajax(function{
    type="POST",
    url:"thefile.php",
    data:"name="+name+"&email="+email.......
    success:function(response){
      $('.radio3').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });

});

}); //end of (ready)
```

in PHP which **is not** a good idea me thinks

```
//submit form get the data etc...
$buttons = array("button1" => 0, "button2" = 1);

//displaying the buttons
foreach($buttons as $key => $but){
   if($but == 1){
      echo "<input type="radio" name='" . $key . "' disabled='disabled'/>"
   }else{
      echo "<input type="radio"  name='" . $key . "' />
   }
}
```

Comment: i just want in php...........

Comment: who wants, won't get :) i've updated my answer

Comment: $button???$key?????$but????can u  send the clear answer........this code shud be placed in the registration.php or in login.php??

Comment: i gave <input type="radio" name="role" value="1" />Admin in the form

Comment: or url:"thefile.php",(thefile.php???
    data:"name="+name+"&email="+email.......(name,email??)
    success:function(response){
      $('.radio3').attr('disabled', 'disabled');(rodia3??

Comment: You have given a very vague and "poor" question, you haven't stated the files, names or any data. So I would take what code there is an apply it to your mystery question. :)

Comment: i gave name="role" values="1">admmin

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="xy" <? echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> />
```

Comment: i got 3 users to be registered in the registration form through radio button admin,manager and employee... after registration of a  admin the other 2 raadio buttons shud only enable